# Cannot connect mysql on virtual interface 10.0.0.x

Tags: networking, firewall, mysql

I have a trouble to connect mysql running on 10.0.0.5 from 10.0.0.4. This is a virtual network created in Hetzner interface. I think mysql is configured correctly according to a documentation.

[image]

**Backend 10.0.0.4**

```
root@backend:~# mysql -u root --host=10.0.0.5 --protocol=tcp --port=3306
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.5' (115)
root@backend:~# mysql -u literakl --host=10.0.0.5 --protocol=tcp --port=3306 -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.5' (115)

root@backend:~# telnet 10.0.0.5 3306
Trying 10.0.0.5...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

root@backend:~# ssh root@10.0.0.5
The authenticity of host '10.0.0.5 (10.0.0.5)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:iDrbbDdMK1XKRrb0O3lZ899K/oQmTFtu4ju75h+te0Y.
10.0.0.5

root@backend:~# ping 10.0.0.5
PING 10.0.0.5 (10.0.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.75 ms

root@backend:~# nmap 10.0.0.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-30 20:35 CEST
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.5
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 150.32 seconds
```

**Secondary 10.0.0.5**

```
root@secondary:~# less /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
#skip-networking=1
#skip-bind-address

root@secondary:~# ufw status
Status: active
33060                      ALLOW       10.0.0.4
33061                      ALLOW       10.0.0.4
3306                       ALLOW       10.0.0.4
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

root@secondary:~# netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9927594  /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

root@secondary:~# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
mysqld    6749 mysql   21u  IPv4 9927593      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)

root@secondary:~# telnet 10.0.0.5 3306
Trying 10.0.0.5...
Connected to 10.0.0.5.
5.5.5-10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1$(u:]H1mysql_native_password

root@secondary:~# ip address
3: ens10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:00:00:b8:0d:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/32 brd 10.0.0.5 scope global dynamic ens10
       valid_lft 54105sec preferred_lft 54105sec
    inet6 fe80::8400:ff:feb8:d95/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@secondary:~# mysql -u literakl --host=10.0.0.5 --protocol=tcp --port=3306 -p
Your MariaDB connection id is 37
Server version: 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
| User             | Host      |
| literakl         | %         |
| literakl         | localhost |
```

I wonder, what could be wrong? The port 3306 is open on the secondary service. I have even tried to turn off the firewall on both servers but still no luck. Weird.

Update 1:

```
root@secondary:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        10.0.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 ens10
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens10
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0

root@secondary:~# ip route list
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 scope link
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link

root@secondary:~# arp -a
? (10.0.0.1) at d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3 [ether] on ens10
? (172.18.0.3) at 02:42:ac:12:00:03 [ether] on docker_gwbridge
? (172.31.1.1) at d2:74:7f:6e:37:e3 [ether] on eth0
11214.your-cloud.host (195.201.66.70) at 2e:bb:61:a6:0f:84 [ether] on eth0
```

Update 2:

I have created new VPS called ternary, the developer installed just MySQL , there is no Mongo running in Docker (like in the secondary) and I can connect it from the backend. Original routes seems the same on both machines. We suspect that Docker/Swarm might affect the secondary node.

```
root@secondary:~# ip route
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 scope link
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

**New ternary VPS**

```
root@ternary:~# ip route
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 scope link
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link

root@backend:~# mysql --host=10.0.0.6 -u matomo -p matomo
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'matomo'@'10.0.0.4' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have created the virtual network correctly? No route to host usually means the IP is not in the same subnet. Please post your virtual network config.

Comment: I have added an output of ssh and ping to the question. They do work well. Only mysql does not.
I have used Hetzner VPS provider GUI tool to set up the virtual network.  E.g. I did not do any rekkklated cmd line changes and I have no idea how it is created. I will post a screenshot there too.

Comment: Why do you use servers named "Mongo..." (hence dedicated for a MongoDB) for running MySQL? I would first check if the 10.0.0.5 machine is really the one you configure (may be there are two machines using the same IP?). Check if on server and client side the show the same ssh key hash: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10060530/150978 Also a nmap scan of 10.0.0.5 from 10.0.0.4 would show you the open ports.

Comment: MySQL is a dependency of some software I need. The mongo-secondary has a low traffic and a usage in general so I placed MariaDB there. I will check nmap, good idea.

Comment: Run nmap on the network. Strange I do not see either MySQL or Mongo (in docker with exposed port 27017). Something sucks. I think I shall try to build the private network from command line and remove the Hetzner private network.

Comment: First, disable your firewall once and see, but then: 1) Check your arp tables if you've been recreating your VMs a bunch like `arp -a`. 2) Try capturing packets to see which end the issue is on (maybe secondary gets the packets, but can't respond?). usually like `tcpdump -i eth0 port 3306`. 3) See if you have any surprise route entries with `ip route list` and/or in your vSwitch.

Comment: Please add in your post the printout on `10.0.0.4` of the [Routing Table](https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-display-routing-table.html).

Comment: Done. 
The other developer is suspecting Docker to use a conflicting network. There was name=ingress and ciddr=10.0.0.0/24. I actually have no idea of its meaning.

Comment: The mismatched subnet/route mask should be fine unless you mean docker has another subnet not showing in Hetzner. I can see that Secondary `.5` is routing everything through Hetzner's vswitch `.1`, so: 1) could Hetzner have set up its own firewall service? 2) Can you say if `.2` or `.3` can connect to secondary? 3) Try connecting in reverse from `.4` like `telnet 10.0.0.5 3306` - I would expect you to see `Connection refused` instead of only `No route to host` in most circumstances.

Comment: You have two network interfaces, which might cause a routing problem. Please try on `10.0.0.4` the command `traceroute 10.0.0.5`.

Comment: Your subnetting is wrong.  Secondary has ip address inet 10.0.0.5/32 broadcast 10.0.0.5.  Should be 10.0.0.5/24 broadcast 10.0.0.255 i believe

Comment: And how to fix it, please?

Comment: `ip route add 10.0.0.5/24 dev ens10`

Comment: I ran it on secondary:
root@secondary:~# ip route add 10.0.0.5/24 dev ens10
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.

Comment: I was going along with the previous comment, but it's wrong, your subnet is correct.